# How to get flash charstristic from broadcasting beacon?

Tags: android, sensors, ibeacon-android

I am facing problem to read flash (stored data) from sensor.

When i establish connection between android device and sensor, i get Humidity and Temperature from Advertisement packet.

But when i read characteristics from sensor from specific UUID then its return last only `20 bytes` like this.

here is my data

`[105, -104, 124, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: What kind of beacon is this?  A sensor beacon?  What characteristic do you read that returns these data?  Can you show your code that reads the characteristic?

Comment: I have beacon that read Humidity and Temperate from weather every 20 second and store on it. it store last 20 days data it self. i want to read that 20 days data from beacon.